# How do I receive message from a queue existing in one domain from another domain MSMQ

Tags: c#, msmq

We are running a windows service that is supposed to pick up messages from a remote queue.

The remote queue exists in domain **enterprise.org**.

The windows service is running in domain **dmz.enterprise.org** under a local account '.\user'.

The queue has earlier been located on the same server as the windows service and all worked fine but we have been instructed to change this.

For our queue we have set up rights for a specific account, enterprise\QUser that I want to use when picking up messages from queue.

I know it's possible to use an Impersonator... when inside same domain but we are not. And as further input the servers is not in the same forest. Ie enterprise.org and dmz.enterprise.org are in different forests.

**EDIT** We are using private queues.
We have also tried with *everyone* and *anonymous logon* with full control, no authentication and still can't receive messages.**EDIT**

**EDIT2** 
As from Johns input (blog post below) I try to make it more clear...

Since our windows service (in dmz.enterprise.org) only read remote queue it should be adequate with one-way trust from enterprise.org to dmz.dustingroup.org. Is that correct?

Further input; the remote queue is located on a failover cluster on W2012 servers. Might that be of any importance for the issue?
**EDIT2**

Is it possible to somehow programmatically set what credentials to use when connecting to the remote queue?

Comment: Can you clarify - are you saying enterprise.org and dmz.enterprise.org are in different forests?

Comment: Yes, they are in different forests.

Comment: Different forests means a lot more work to get through security. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/06/27/cross-forest-msmq-you-need-to-be-trusting.aspx

Comment: Thanks, John. I have read that post earlier but I didn't really grasped it that time. I reread it and I think I get your point. I will update above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use direct paths, but you cannot create queues that way. See [this](http://www.k2underground.com/blogs/chrisg/archive/2008/04/25/msmq-and-multiple-forests.aspx)

Comment: When using private queues you need to use direct paths and yes, we are.